# Does PostgreSQL exist on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I knew there was a version of PostgreSQL installed on OS X Mountain Lion and if you want to work with this database engine you must install a new version and make some changes (http://nextmarvel.net/blog/2011/09/brew-install-postgresql-on-os-x-lion /). I didn't do this at that time because it was not necessary for me.

Now I have my Mac with OS X Mavericks (clean install) and if I run `psql -- version` as can be seen in this article (http://russbrooks.com/2010/11/25/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x), the terminal tells me that there is no such command.

```
~ » psql --version                                                                                                                                                          
zsh: correct 'psql' to 'sl' [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: psql
```

Does PostgreSQL get installed by default when I do a clean install of OS X Mavericks?

If i want to try PostgreSQL on Mavericks, do I just need to run `brew install postgresql` and it`d be OK?

Has anyone tried this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't use a Mac but I have been told that "Postgres.app" is pretty easy to install and use: http://postgresapp.com/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it should be safe to `brew install postgresql`, provided `brew doctor` indicates no problems.

My preferred approach is always to leave OS X builtins untouched, and use Homebrew to install separate versions of everything I'd like to work with. I've tried using OS X builtins in the past, and things have a way of getting messy in a hurry, especially when updating OS X.

Comment: Ok, when ran `brew install postgresql`, no has no apparent problems with new PostgreSQL version installed. Now when run `postgres  --version`, i get a success answer : `postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.1`. Thanks Aaron!

Comment: This seems to work:
http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/

Comment: Yep, lunchy works, although I've only just discovered `brew services`: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew :o

Comment: …DON'T USE `brew services`, it's a horribly broken contribution and likely on its way out for now.

Answer (score 10):

For everyone who is looking for guide about how to install and configure postgres on the fresh Mavericks installation: http://marcinkubala.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/postgresql-on-os-x-mavericks/

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Can I suggest copying the contents of your blog post into your answer here? That way the answer is good even if the link should die, and based on number of views, this question deserves a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can download different versions of PostgreSQL [from Apple](http://opensource.apple.com/source/PostgreSQL/).

Answer (score 0):

Also for a development environment you can use Postgres.app (http://postgresapp.com/):

> [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) is a simple, native Mac OS X app that runs in the menubar without the need of an installer. Open the app, and you have a PostgreSQL server ready and awaiting new connections. Close the app, and the server shuts down.
>   [http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/ ]