# I installed PostgreSQL on mavericks, but running `which psql` does not do anything. Did it install correctly?

Tags: postgresql, osx-mavericks

I installed PostgreSQL using the [downloadable graphic installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx).  I'm able to launch pgAdmin which is PostgreSQL's GUI.  However, when I run `which psql` on the terminal, I'm not getting any path (and [based on what I read here](http://od-eon.com/blogs/calvin/postgresql-cheat-sheet-beginners/) it should yield a path provided postgres successfully installed).

After looking at this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611505/does-postgresql-exist-on-os-x-mavericks), I should have done it via homebrew.  Should I uninstall the PostgreSQL that I got via the graphic installer, and re-install using homebrew?

Noob here, and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: If `which` doesn't find it, then `psql` is not in the `PATH`, just add the directory containing it and you should be fine.

Comment: You'll need to add the `bin` directory for PostgreSQL to the `PATH`. Isn't that part of the install documentation? (BTW, there's no particular reason you should use one install method over another; the Rails people like to use homebrew, that's all).

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed it using Postgres.app, the path to your binary should be under /Applications/Postgres.app/.  Try running this at the terminal, you can see on my system it's under /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin.

```
$: find /Applications/Postgres.app/ -name "psql" -print
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql
```

If you then want to add this to your path variable, you could use [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/).